# IE - footer text issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, footer

I am facing the following issue in IE7
[image]

Whereas in Chrome, FF and Opera it looks fine
[image]

Can anyone figure out why I am getting this issue, last few characters coming down to the div

```
#footer
{
bottom:0;
clear:both;
background: url("images/footer.png") repeat-x #8DC63F;
position:relative;
float:left;
width:100%;
}


.footer-text
{
text-align:center;
font-family:'Tahoma';
font-size:10pt;
color: #000000;
top:20px;
margin:10px auto;
}



 <div id="footer">
 <p class="footer-text">Home | Services | About Us | Products | Contact Us</p>
 <p class="footer-text">2011 &copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>  
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. just remove the float style from the footer. and see what happens.

Comment: removed float:left, worked fine in IE7, but misalignment in FF, Chrome and Opera http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/8847/44cssissue.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the float style from the footer and add `text-align:center;`
 to the footer